# Update Explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a cursor which retrieves trip detail of trains. And when I loop through the records I update ETA (Arrival Time) for next station. Again this value is used to calculate ETD  (Departure Time) at that station. I wish to use the updated value of ETA to calculate ETD when the record fetches the next station for that trip rather than the old value when opening the cursor. Is this possible?

```
CURSOR CUR_SCN IS
SELECT TRIP_ID,
TRAIN_ID,
STATION_ID,
ETA
FROM TRIP_DTL
WHERE ....;

FOR rec IN CUR_SCN
   calculate and update ETD for current rec.STATION_ID

   ld_eta := Business logic goes here for calculating next station ETA for the TRIP

   UPDATE TRIP_DTL
   SET ETA = ld_eta
   WHERE STATION_ID = next station
   AND TRIP_ID = rec.TRIP_ID;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Adam Hawkes'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282009/458741) says there is no way to "get" the new values in a cursor for loop, however there are ways around this.

1. Use a [global temporary table](http://psoug.org/reference/gtt.html). Update this, query again and then put everything in your actual table - I don't really like this route but it'll do what you want.
2. [Bulk collect](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html) your data into a user-defined type and use the values in this to calculate what you want. Something like the following. This has the benefit of less DML being done on the table and you can use rowid to update so updates will be quicker.

   ```
   declare

      cursor cur_scn is
       SELECT rowid as rid, TRIP_ID, TRAIN_ID, STATION_ID, ETA
         FROM TRIP_DTL
        WHERE ....
        ORDER BY SOMETHING;

       type t__scn is table of cur_scn%rowtype index by binary_integer;
       t_scn t__scn;

   begin

      open cur_scn;
      fetch cur_scn bulk collect into t_scn;

      for i in t_scn.first + 1.. t_scn.last loop
         t_scn(i).eta := t_scn(i - 1).eta + business_logic;
      end loop;

      forall i in t_scn.first .. t_scn.last
         update trip_dtl
            set eta = t_scn(i).eta
          where rowid = t_scn(i).rid;

      close cur_scn;

   end;
   ```
3. I don't really like the way you have to update everything the whole time, but I can't off the top of my head think of a much better way of storing the data, but you should investigate.

Answer (score 1):

When the cursor is opened, there is a fixed view of the data. The only way to get the "new" values is to re-query.